# Database Structure (zero-to-one-to-many relationships)

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, relational-database

I am currently working on creating a database for a community partnership program for educational purposes. The structure of the DB should be simple be as stated above, the data tends to overlap in various of ways. There are four main categories; Internships, Jobs, Summer/Yearly Programs, and Other. Followed by an Address book/Contacts list.

This is the part where the data is difficult to structure. The employer and has relate to the "employment posting" and doing so relates to the school's academic departments, 6. But some employers require more than one. This data will then be followed by, how many openings?, posting date, follow up contact date, Student hired? if so, student evaluation, and Notes.

I'm not asking how to create the DB, but how would I organize and structure such a complex data collection? I have managed DB's, (putting in information) and I know how to build from scratch as needed. But I have been tasked with structuring somethings like this.

Here is an image of information needed to collect. (More  or less)

[Click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA75E.jpg)

Comment: Try to design a data model showing your entities, keys, relationships, and cardinalities. Then ask specific questions about parts about which you are uncertain. This platform doesn't serve to design your data model for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck at the "How do I get started?" stage, I suggest that you start at a very high level (the conceptual data model), then refine only a bit to the logical data model, then to physical data model.  Here is a [short explanation of the 3 different kinds of data model](https://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/data-modeling-levels.html).  (Don't worry that it appears to be about data warehouses - these bits aren't specific to data warehouses.)

For a bit more detail, there is another [article on data modeling](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html) - again, don't worry that it appears in the context of Agile - this is generally useful stuff even if you're not using Agile.

Another two things that might help are these questions (in this order):

1. What questions do I need the database to answer?
2. What information does it need to provide a home for? (Why?  If it's not covered by part of the answer to the first question, challenge why it's needed.)

Comment: Thanks for the links to models, and yes you are correct when I'm at the "how to get started" stage. I surrounded by many overlaps and items they want to track.

Example. 

Company A wants an intern, they only have 2 openings, and want either a student from Dept. 1,3, or 6. The Company is more associated with Dept 3. So company information needs to be recorded. (company, assoc. dept., and who the contact is.) One company may have 3 people in contact with us, so that needs to be factored. I'm focusing on this bit first, how to track companies and contacts.

Comment: I often find it helps to stay away from a computer at this stage (conceptual data model), and use something like a whiteboard or paper and pen.  It helps me to get everything complete at a high level, rather than doing all the detail of just a part and then running into problems later with high level bits I'd missed.  Also, get your CDM reviewed by Important People before you go into detail - it saves rework.